# Use MVC razor function inside <script type="text/template"></script>

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, templates, razor

I am trying to solve this issue from last 6 hours, but couldn't complete it.

here I have one template script in my Razor view.

```
<script type="text/template" id="Blog_Post_Template">   

    {{if DescType == "FULL"}}
            ${FDesc}
    {{/if}}

    {{if DescType == "SORT"}}
            ${SDesc}
    {{/if}}

</script>
```

Now, what I want is to use Razor function inside this template.

> Let's take @Html.Raw(), **I want to use @Html.Raw() in   ${FDesc}, and  ${SDesc}.**

I tried many escape sequences like,

```
@Html.Raw("'${FDesc}'")
@Html.Raw("\'${FDesc}\'")
```

And  mane more solutions, but I came up at the point where I started.

**Input is like, A simple text with html parameters**

```
<p> Test this </p>
```

> Output will be a **html**

**Appreciate**, if anyone can resolve it..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? If you want to execute C# code, put it in code block/ or use `@` prefix.

Comment: text/template provides less support, I want to use @html.raw() function inside script..but it does not allow me..

Comment: What have you tried ? What error /output are you getting ? What is your expected output ?

Comment: and what is `DescType` ? Is it a C# variable ? js variable ?

Comment: all are js variables..

Comment: Keep in mind that your C# code gets executed before the js code.

Comment: yes, but how do you combine both? and particulary in templates..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, After 3 days of R&D, I found solution.

BTW, we can't use razor is template as @chris said, but there is alternative
And it's very very simpler.

Answer is **Html** tag inside template, see below example.

> {{**html** Value}}

and my full code now looks like,

```
<script type="text/template" id="Blog_Post_Template">   

    {{if DescType == "FULL"}}
          {{html FDesc}} // which will now give me pure html
    {{/if}}

    {{if DescType == "SORT"}}
          {{html SDesc}}
    {{/if}}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that you understand the effect of the client-server nature of HTTP here. Razor codes runs server-side, while your JavaScript/template code will run client-side, after the server has already done its work and returned a response. As a result, something like `@Html.Raw("'${FDesc}'")` will literally output `'${FDesc}'`, not the raw HTML that `${FDesc}` will *eventually* evaluate to. If you need to ensure that that template variable is printed without being HTML-escaped, then you need to rely on functionality in your JavaScript templating library for that, not Razor.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your template in some html element such as div

```
<script type="text/template" id="Blog_Post_Template">   
<div>
    {{if DescType == "FULL"}}
            ${FDesc}
    {{/if}}

    {{if DescType == "SORT"}}
            ${SDesc}
    {{/if}}
</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what's server and client side but it maybe I'm not familiar with the templating you are using, but server side evaluation of a variable and then rendering client side with no elements avaiable can be achieved using the `<text></text>` elements:

```
<script type="text/template" id="Blog_Post_Template">   
    @if(DescType == "FULL")
    {
        <text>${FDesc}</text>
    }
    ...
</script>
```

Maybe this will help?